# Modify DateTimeImmutable with input value

Tags: php, forms, datetime, input

I need to modify the '+1 month' with the input value from the form.

Now, I have it like this

```
public function buy($userId, ProductForm $form): void
    {

        $user = $this->users->get($userId);
        $product = $this->products->get($form->productId);

        $user->addOrder(
            $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            $now->modify('+1 month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );

        $this->users->save($user);
    }

    In ProductForm 

      public function periodList(): array
    {
        return [
            '+1 month' => '1 Month',
            '+2 month' => '2 Month',
            '+3 month' => '3 Month',
        ];
    }
```

I tried to get the date of $now + form value, which can be 1 to 3 months.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please show us more code. Where do you access the modified value and see that it is incorrect. What does addOrder do? More details and code will allow for us to help you better

Comment: I have updated the code. Just need add to $now + the form period .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();

$formattedPlusAMonth = $now->modify('+1 month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

You should read up on the **DateTimeImmutable** class. It never modifies the source (which is why it's called immutable). You'll need to capture what it returns in a new variable.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

Comment: You are right, it shows that it never modifies, beginner error.
Now, I have it like this

$now = new \DateTimeImmutable();

$now->modify('+1 month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

I tried to get the date of $ now + form value, which can be 1 to 3 months.

Comment: Update your original question with the latest code. Also, I still don't see where you assign the new value in your last commment